# Asymptotic of interesting recurrence relation

Tags: asymptotics, recurrence-relation

I want to study the asymptotic behavior of the following recurrence relation:

$y_1=1$;

$y_{n+1}=y_{n}+(1+\frac{y_n}{n})^{-n}\ \ $ for $n\ge 1$.

I made an initial attempt and guessed that $y_{n} \sim Log(n)$.
Any referrence or hint about this might be helpful. Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Please lay out how/why the techniques laid our at [our reference question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2789/solving-or-approximating-recurrence-relations-for-sequences-of-numbers) don't help you. Given that you have a guess, have you tried proving it correct? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: @Raphael. You might have been too quick on the trigger here. I don't see anything in the reference question that would help the OP with a problem like this.

Comment: You might try asking this over on [math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/)